# Can command argument and onclick event be added to a div?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, jquery-plugins

I am have a photo album(not gallery) which previews the photos withing it. The albums are dynamically generated depending on number of albums associated with the user. I want to add on click event to it so that when a person clicks an album it takes him to the photos within that album. I am beginner so I do not exactly know how it can be done. But I think adding command arguments should do the trick.

ASPX CODE:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt5.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    string q = "select  imageurl from photos where albumid='" 
                                        + dt5.Rows[i]["albumid"].ToString() + "'";
    dt6 = dbo.Getdt(q);
    a = dt6.Rows[0]["imageurl"].ToString();
    b = dt6.Rows[1]["imageurl"].ToString();
    c = dt6.Rows[2]["imageurl"].ToString();
    a= a.Substring(1, a.Length - 1);
    b = b.Substring(1, b.Length - 1);
    c = c.Substring(1, c.Length - 1);
  %> 
   <div   class="image_stack" style="margin-left:300px ; right: 418px;"   
        runat="server">
       <img   class="stackphotos photo1" src="<%: a %>"   />
       <img   class="stackphotos photo2" src="<%: b %>"  />
       <img "   class="stackphotos photo3" src="<%: c %>" />
   </div>
     <br /><br /><br /><br />
<% } %>
```

In above code image_stack is the div which is used to show album using Jquery plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Going purely on what you've posted, this would let you handle "selecting" an album image:

```
<script>

    $(function() {
        $('div.image_stack').on('click', 'img.stackphotos', function(event) {
            // handle click event
        });
    });

</script>
```

What you do in the click event is up to you, as I'm not entirely sure what you mean by

> ...takes him to the photos within that album.

If the intent is to redirect the user to a new page, you really should just wrap the images in hyperlink tags and use the "natural" HTTP mechanisms.

**EDIT:**

To answer your question in the comments, you have two choices:

1) Wrap the image in a anchor:

```
<a href="url_to_your_detail_page"><img class="stackphotos photo1" src="<%: a %>" /></a>
```

I have no idea what the `href` value would be, as that depends on knowing how your site is setup.

2) Use JavaScript to redirect:

```
window.location.replace('url_to_your_detail_page');
```

MDN has a good reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location

In either case, you would have to generate the proper URL when creating the page markup.

Comment: ok supposing i want to redirect to another page, how can i do that in this case? I would also need the albumid of the div which has been clicked.

Answer (score 0):

try below code to add Click and Pass Command Argument on Div using Jquery :

```
$(".image_stack").click(function(event){
//Do here whatever you want
});
```